# Автоматическая фокусировка внизу страницы

Tags: html, css, javascript

У меня есть страница и нужно сделать так, чтобы при каждом её посещении показывалась нижняя часть "как будто пользователь прокрутил её сам в самый низ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самый низ добавляем `<div id="down"></div>` и к ссылке прикручиваем якорь например `page.html#down`

В `javascript`

```
window.scroll(0,document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
```

Comment: Нужно без всяких якорей и тому подобного.
Пример: ВКонтатке, в личных сообщениях. Там сразу прокручивается вниз

Comment: Попробуйте вариант в javascript для начала, хотябы посмотрите как он работает